# Сжатие CSS файлов средствами php

Tags: php

Есть функция сжатия css файлов.
 Как можно удалить все пробелы после знака `,`,  `:`,  `;`,  `)`

```
function compression_files($files_css, $new_file) {
        // получаем содержимое всех css файлов
        $content_css = "";
        foreach($files_css as $one_file){
            $content_css .= @file_get_contents($one_file);
            if(!$content_css) return false; // если какой-то из файлов не получилось прочитать
        }

        // удаляем комментарии 
        $content_css = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!','', $content_css);
        // удаляем табуляции и переходы на новую строку
        $content_css = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n","\t"),'', $content_css);
        // удаляем повторяющиеся пробелы
        $content_css = preg_replace('/ {2,}/','', $content_css);

        // сохраняем результат в файл
        $css_file = fopen ($new_file, "w+");  
        fwrite($css_file, $content_css);  
        $result_save = fclose($css_file); 

        // вернем результат сохранения
        return $result_save;
    }
    ////  Пример использования этой функции:  ////

    // массив с путями до css файлов
    //$css_array = array('style.css','main.css');
    $css_array = array('style.css');

    // путь, куда будет сохранен сжатый файл
    $new_file = "compression.css";
    // вызываем функцию сжатия
    $result = compression_files($css_array, $new_file);



    if(file_exists($new_file)){
       echo "Файл успешно создан";
    }else{
       echo "Ошибка";
    }
```

Comment: Зачем необходимо создавать очередной минимизатор? [CSSO](https://github.com/css/csso/blob/master/docs/index/index.ru.md), на php - [раз](https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify) и [два](https://github.com/mrclay/minify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$content_css = preg_replace('/([,:;)]) /','$1', $content_css);`

В этом выражении все что в круглых скобках, так называемая группа захвата, каждая такая группа может быть использована в выражении на что менять и там обозначена как `$1`, если бы были еще круглые скобки были бы `$2` и т.д.

Квадрантные скобки - перечисление символов, т.е. в этом месте строки ожидается любой из перечисленных в скобках символов. Ну и пробел поле скобок обозначает сам себя. `preg_replace` заменяет найденное выражение целиком на то, что после запятой, мы в данном случае нашли, например `,`, но запятую нам удалять не надо, а только пробел после нее. поэтому в правой части и стоит `$1`. В итоге получаем *заменить запятую с пробелом на запятую*.

И мне `$content_css = preg_replace('/ {2,}/','', $content_css);` не нравится, она удаляет все двойные пробелы, вообще удаляет. т.е. если в строке 3 пробела, то все ok, а если четное кол-во - то ни одного не останется. Если такое поведение и задумывалось то ok, просто не знаю на сколько привередлив css.
Если один пробел от любых строк пробелов оставить то
`$content_css = preg_replace('/ + /',' ', $content_css);`

В последнем выражении все элементарно, `+` обозначает повтор предыдущего символа 1 и более раз. Т.е. *заменить один и более пробелов и еще один пробел на один пробел*

Comment: Спасибо работает. если можно подскажите как удалить пробел перед знаком `{ `.

Comment: $content_css = preg_replace('/ +\\{/','', $content_css);  Поизучайте регулярки на досуге, полезная штука :)

Comment: Спасибо. подскажите сайт, где можа потестировать регулярки.

Comment: https://regex101.com/    Сейчас еще распишу коменты в ответе, для наглядности

Comment: Да, при тестировании выражений на том сайте они записываются в чистом виде, а при переносе в php регулярки надо заключать в кавычки, из за этого все обратные косые (`\\`) необходимо удваивать, что бы в регулярке они остались неизменными.